# How can I define a Conditional Compilation Symbol in a .NET Core project programmatically when my NuGet package is installed?

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget, .net-core, project.json

I have a NuGet package that contains a PowerShell script which sets a conditional compilation symbol on the target project when the package is installed. This works fine for all projects except for those that use project.json files (e.g. .NET Core, UWP).

My script accesses the `$project.ConfigurationManager` instances of the target project, and adds the symbol to the `DefineConstants` entry if necessary. This does not work for projects with project.json files - in fact, I cannot even see the `$project` object when I try to access a .NET Core project via PowerShell. The following picture illustrates this: whereas a classic .NET and PCL project are accessible, the last `System.__ComObject` probably represents the .NET Core project that cannot be accessed.

[image: .NET Core project cannot be accessed via PowerShell]

**So how can I set a conditional compilation symbol in a .NET Core project programmatically?** Is there another way to do that instead of using an install.ps1 script? I know that, basically, I have to find the project JSON file and add the following entry if not present

```
"buildOptions": {
  "define": [ "MY_CONDITIONAL_COMPILATION_SYMBOL" ]
}
```

but I'm stuck on how to get there.

Comment: PowerShell in NuGet package is dead and you cannot do anything like that any more.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the info - do you know if there will be any other functionality to replace install.ps1 scripts?

Comment: no. NuGet will only be the ZIP containers for static assemblies.